# How to add radio button property to Custom View using NSButton and NSTextfield

Tags: swift, nsview, nstextfield, nsbutton

I m creating a custom NSView, it has NSBUTTON of type radio and NSTextfield. Right now, it doesnot show property of radio button i.e. if I select one radio button, other radio buttons should go off. Any fix

the layer of views is like this
NSCUSTOMBUTTON has NSTEXTFIELD AND NSBUTTON, THEY are then added to the stackview, which is further added to the super view.

Comment: Do the radio buttons have the same superview and the same action?

Comment: yes, they have same super view and i tried adding the same action

Comment: Does each `NSCustomButton` contain one `NSButton`?

Comment: yes, it's a super class, so it has only one NSButton

Comment: I guess, it's the issue with super view, because of the additional layer of NSCustombutton, radio buttons properties are overshadowed. Any fix

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish, why do you need `NSCUSTOMBUTTON`?

Comment: basically, i want to add some custom properties like wrap and alignment and stuff to the title of button. NSbutton doesn’t have that properties like there are some hacks but it has too many corner cases

Comment: The radio functionality is implemented by `NSButtonCell`. You'll have to implement your own.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit: I found the answer, basically you have to implement your own delegate function, that handles mousedown event and then add the functionality of radio button where you extend the delegate.

```
private func handleClickAction(_ clickedButton: ChoiceButton) {
        guard isRadioGroup else { return }
        if previousButton?.value != clickedButton.value {
            previousButton?.state = .off
            previousButton = clickedButton
        }
    }
```